# PDO query returning null?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

```
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE session = :session AND id = :id");
    $query->bindValue(":session", $session);
    $query->bindValue(":id", $id);

    try {
        $query->execute();
        $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $result;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        return false;
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
```

The array "result" returns null, the databases and values are correct in the query, I echoed the values it were going to buy before it queried and the database contained a row with those values. The database name is also correct. I also checked the whole thing with different return variables and that indicated, every time, that it was the array that was empty.

What I'm trying to do is fetch data from a database depending on what session values the cookies have.

Comment: Does it still return empty if you remove the WHERE clause from your query?

Comment: Stupid question, but did you enable exception error handling for that PDO instance?

Comment: I don' think I have a "WHERE" thing? And yes, I did, I have this "$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);"

Comment: what is in `$session` and `$id`?

Comment: What do you get when you remove `WHERE session = :session AND id = :id`? That should return everything in the table.

Comment: $query->execute(); Put this before try block.

Comment: You sure about your `$session` and `$id` values? No trailing whitespace etc? Use `var_dump($var)` for a more detailed output for debugging.